# Comments moderator tool tab for app admins

Tags: facebook, comments

I have 1 admin and 1 tester for my comment plugin App. I know that I can access comments using the URL https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments/?id=APPID

But Is it possible for the admins to recieve timeline notifications about new comments, so we don't have to access this URL all the time?

Comment: admins are not recieving notifications, just the moderators

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure the answer is No, as I would like to have this for the comment plugins I have to moderate.  However this is an excellent idea for a feature enhancement.  Please log it as a bug/enhancement at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs